# Good free sqlite gui tool

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I would like to ask if there is any free SQLite gui tool for an android device. I try some but they are not good enough.

Regards,
Jimmy

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you want gui file for windows or mac

Comment: Laalto -> Oh, is it? Okay, next time won't post something like this

Comment: For windows::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332250/windows-gui-tool-for-sqlite3

Comment: Vijay -> As written, it is for android.

Comment: FYI, it's `iaalto`, not `Laalto` (Uppercase **i** not lowercase **L**). @Iaalto is one of our most influent SQLite experts, together with CL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQLite Firefox Manager` is a great tool. You can get it from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/?src=search).

**Steps :**

- Get the database file through Android Device Monitor which will be in `data/data/Your-Application-package/databases/Your-db-file`.
- Pull that db file and save it with file extension `.sqlite`.
- Open `Sql Manager`, choose attach the database and select the pulled file where you stored.

You can now view the schema, add stuffs and whatever you want. Later, push the file into that location where you initially pulled.

Comment: I cannot access https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/your-package/database/

Comment: Are you sure it is Android Device Manager? It seems to me that this app is used to help people locate their missing android device.

Comment: Android Device Monitor*

Comment: I went to play store and I can only find device monitor. I assume this is what you mean.

Comment: You don't need to download an app. If you are using Android studio, it will be available next to Android SDK Manager in top tools section. Click the available online device and choose DDMS. If you're using eclipse, give a google search how to open DDMS.

Comment: I have written another question. Perhaps Yuva, you knew the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866987/copy-sqlite-db-file-from-android-terminal-to-windows-os