# Copy sqlite db file from Android terminal to Windows OS

Tags: java, android, sqlite, terminal

I want to copy the sqlite database from data/data/[package name]/databases/ to Windows Operating system.

Currently, I am inside Android Terminal shell of Android studio and my current path is /data/data/example.com.sensor/databases.

There is a sqlite file in this directory. The name is sensor.sqlite.

This is perhaps an easy question for experience user like you.
However, I have spent 2 hours yet I find the result.

Thank you.

Regards,

Jimmy

Comment: Is your device rooted?  If not, I don't think you can do this.  Private application files are only readable to the owning application; not even `adb` can read them, so you can't copy them from device.

Comment: Ya it is not rooted.

Comment: Do you have ddms tool ?

Comment: You mean this -> Dalvik Debug Monitor Server?

Comment: yes do you have that

Comment: Ya, I am using android studio. I have it inside android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your device is not rooted, you cannot do this from outside of the application.  If it's your application, you can add a temporary routine into the application to copy the database to public storage, then use `adb` or MTP to copy the file to your Windows computer.

Or, you can just root your device.

Answer (score 1):

See below attached image.
* To pull any file(note here you can pull only file,not folder).
-> As you can see just select your device from Device tab (On left).
-> Then Goto File Explorer tab and find path of your database.

As in image you can see I have open database directory of `com.android.browser` package application.

[image]

If you got some problem of finding your app package there, See another screen-shot below.And find app as directed there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Steps :**

1. Open Android Device Monitor.

[image]

2. Make sure your device is online & if your device is online, you will see like this in left side (Available device). Choose your device & in the centre at `File Explorer` tab, you can see the db file exists. The path is `data/data/Your-Application-package/databases/Your-db-file`

[image]

3. In the right top side, click `Pull` once you selected your db file and save it with extension `.sqlite`.